# Using a Swagger API definition to generate a server API Controller for ASP MVC

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, swagger

I have generated an API definition using the [Swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/). I want to generate the Controller that serves the API, ie inherits from ApiController. Is this possible? I notice it is possible to generate the C# classes required to consume the API (from the menu in the online editor - generate client) but the menu list to generate server code does not include MVC or similar C# functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own plugin for [Swagger Code Generator](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate C# server code and thus contribute to enriching it.